# Java program not displaying on high DPI screens

Tags: java, windows, screen-resolution

I am very new to Java programing but am managing a deprecated Java software as a part of my job. The old program renders perfectly on lower resolution screens but as the company moves to a higher DPI line of devices (primarily Microsoft Surfaces), the program is very small. I found many ways online to adjust the resolution of other programs through the use of Manifest files but can't seem to get anything to work. I also saw that the swing.properties file can be changed to fix it, but the program doesn't use swing. Are there any external files that can be used to change the resolution for this program?

The issue arises on Windows 10 high DPI devices and the program comes with it's own version of Java installed in the users AppData folder and thus does NOT use the Java installed regularly on the device.

Comment: You might want to include what library/platform you are using for the program. You say you aren't using Swing, but what are you using? SWT, something else? BTW: Is the program not displaying at all (title), or too small (question body)?

Comment: Do you tried to run with a newer Java version ? In general Java is backward compatible with old byte code. 
Do you have the sources ?

Comment: The java.exe version that is included with the program is 8.0.660.18. I honestly don't know what is used in regards to creating the UI (and frankly am new enough that I don't know what to look for), I didn't develop the program and the company that has suggested that I upgrade the system (which is on the docket, but not for 6 months minimum) to use the new webapp.

Comment: There are no detours; you have to understand that there are many factors that could explain this. So you will have to look into your current product; and try to understand how to reduce that to a [mcve] ... and when you got that, we (and probably you yourself) can figure what to do.

Comment: Simplest is to set the display to lower resolution when using the program.  If that's not possible there are apps which can emulate the same thing for readers with poor eyesight.

Comment: I have used a new java version. It has not been any different. I do not have source code; it is a gradebook application developed by Pearson before their PowerSchool team broke off into a separate company

Comment: I have successfully solved similar problems in Java apps by using microsoft Manifest files, but as you have written Manifest does not help which is strange. Look into JAR file which libraries (SWING, AWT, SWT, Qt Jambi, ...) are used for GUI and than look for more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried several different solutions with limited success. The only one which worked for me was to adjust the properties of the java.exe and/or the javaw.exe executables as described in this superuser answer:

https://superuser.com/a/1207925

This worked perfectly for me.